# How to install mysql-server in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

I have mariadb  in my ubuntu system but it is not working properly , so i want to again install mysql in my system .

For Remove mariadb i have run these commands .

1. sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
2. sudo mv /etc/mysql/ /tmp/mysql_configs/
3. nano /etc/apt/sources.list
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6

but after step 5 it's give me these errors :

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient18 : Depends: mysql-common (= 5.6.30-1ubuntu14.04)
 mariadb-server-5.5 : Breaks: mysql-server-5.6
                      Breaks: virtual-mysql-server
 mariadb-server-core-5.5 : Conflicts: mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: mysql-client-5.6 (>= 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
                    Recommends: mysql-common-5.6 but it is not going to be installed
                    Breaks: virtual-mysql-server
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.datastax.com/community/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/debian.datastax.com_community_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.datastax.com/community/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/debian.datastax.com_community_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Can anyone give me suggestion how can i install mysql in my system . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you run  'apt-get -f install' as suggested by the output?

Comment: @ADyson yes i have run that command but i did not get any positive result .

Comment: what result did you get?

Comment: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.6.30-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys', which is also in package mariadb-server-core-5.5 5.5.47-1ubuntu0.14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common_5.6.30-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: have you tried attempting to purge the mariadb-server package instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to update the system.

```
sudo apt update && upgrade
```

then perform the MySQL installation commands and follow the instructions.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Once it has done. try to open MySQL.

```
sudo mysql
```

try to check the authentication method each of your MySQL user accounts uses with the following command in the MySQL terminal:

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

this will return users with authentication_string.
Change the MySQL root password with the following command.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Flush Privileges which tells the server to reload the grant tables and put your new changes into effect

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple to install mysql on ubuntu , just follow these steps :

**Step 1 :** update the system

```
sudo apt update
```

**Step 2 :** Install mysql package

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

**Step 3 :** Once the installation is completed, the MySQL service will start automatically. To check whether the MySQL server is running, type:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql
```

The output of the following command should be :

```
OUTPUT
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-06-20 11:30:23 PDT; 5min ago
Main PID: 17382 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 27 (limit: 2321)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
       `-17382 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**Step 4 :** Securing MySQL

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

select one of the three levels of password validation policy(strong recommended).Set your password ,and then type y(yes) to all the questions , this will improve the security .

**Step 5 :** Once it has done. open MySQL by typing the following command :

```
sudo mysql
```

**Step 6 :** If you want to login to your MySQL server as root from an external program such as phpMyAdmin , then type these commands inside mysql.

```
mysql>ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'strong_password';
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql>exit;
```

After this you will be successfully able to run mysql , for this open terminal and type.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Now type your password.

Congo! you are done with installing mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson from continuous deployment test. You MUST do this purge mysql-common. You CANNOT put mariadb and mysql in the same system, they want their own mysql-common and not sharing them. Which many other API wrapped around it to connect to those server.

And you must comment all the repo pointing to mariadb. Otherwise it will install the same version again from mariadb.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-common
# Put back the mysql-common , make sure you use the new mysql repo,
# remarks mariadb repo
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Always check whether any OTHER file or folder contains mariadb repo.

```
cd /etc/apt
fgrep -lR "maria"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way for this is installing the synaptic package manager by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

And then open synaptic by:

```
sudo synaptic
```

Then search for the package you have installed, mariadb, and mark it for complete removal and press apply.

And these commands  to install mysql-server

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to install mysql on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

You'll be asked to create a new password for `root` user. Set a good password and you're ready to go.

You can also follow  this [youtube videos](https://youtu.be/HHOiUCt01JI) for installation and basic understanding for Mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y
```

if setup password

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

if set new user

```
sudo mysql
>CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
>exit

sudo systemctl restart mysql
```